# HTTP POST request through PROXY php

Tags: php, http, post, curl, proxy

I want send data via Http Post through proxy using CURL on PHP 
I had try to do it but without result !! Please any help !

Answer (score 2):

Use [cURL](http://php.net/curl) normally, but before you do use [this function](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) to set your proxy configuration:

> curl_setopt — Set an option for a cURL transfer

```
bool curl_setopt ( resource $ch , int $option , mixed $value )
```

Use the following options to control the proxy for your curl commands:

> CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL - TRUE to tunnel through a given HTTP proxy.
>
> CURLOPT_PROXY - The HTTP proxy to tunnel requests through.

There are also various other `CURLOPT_*` that lets you do things like set up authentication for your proxy, specify different ports etc...